# Why is this incorrect YAML syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

I'm running a program in Ruby on Rails and have an array of hashes set up in YAML. I'm getting an ArgumentError apparently for having an opening curly brace on the same line as a closing brace for the previous hash.

For example, I have:

```
features: [
  {
    name: lorem ipsum,
    bullets: [
      "bullet 1",
      "bullet 2"
    ]
  },{
    name: lorem ipsum 2,
    bullets: [
    ...
  }
]
```

and it gives me the error. However when I place the opening curly brace on a new line like so:

```
  },
  {
    name: lorem ipsum 2,
    ...
```

it works fine.

I'm using Ruby v. 1.8.7, Rails v. 3.2.1 and Rails Config v. 0.2.4 to read in the YAML file and access it in my app.

Any ideas how to make YAML accept my syntax without doing it the latter way?

Comment: I'm a little surprised it works at all; that's atypical YAML.

Comment: That looks like some unholy YAML and JSON hybrid.

Comment: YAML is a superset of json these days (see http://yaml.org/spec/1.2 )

Comment: **See also:** https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html (previous item is 404)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

YAML doesn't use braces, brackets, etc. Instead, everything will already parse as a hash as-is, and you only need to insert hyphens in front of your list items:

```
features:
- name: lorem ipsum
  bullets:
  - bullet 1
  - bullet 2
- name: lorem ipsum 2
  bullets:
  - ...
```

Loading this will give you:

```
{"features"=>[
  {
    "name"=>"lorem ipsum", 
    "bullets"=>["bullet 1", "bullet 2"]
  },
  {
    "name"=>"lorem ipsum 2",
    "bullets"=>["..."]
  }
]}
```

Comment: According to the current [YAML spec](http://yaml.org/spec/1.0/#id2489726), YAML does indeed have braces and brackets.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby 1.8 uses the Syck library to parse yaml, which only implements version 1.0 of the YAML spec (and is also unmaintained etc.).

With a more current YAML parser (such as psych, available in ruby 1.9) that supports version 1.1 of the yaml spec, your file parses. Just do

```
require 'psych'
require 'yaml'
```

to ensure that you are using psych (check the value of `YAML::ENGINE`). Doesn't look like psych is available for ruby 1.8 though

It is however slightly unusual looking yaml, at least in the ruby world - Dylan's reformatting of it is more common. 
According to the [spec](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) yaml is these days actually a superset of JSON (which had passed me by!)

Comment: Interesting. Where would I place these lines and check the value of YAML::ENGINE?

Comment: Bundler actually does this for you, so when you upgrade to 1.9 (and as long as your machine has libyaml installed) this should get called for you. Checking YAML::ENGINE is just to rule out anything else resetting your choice of YAML engine (versions of delayed job < 3.0 for example). I would just check from the rails console.

Answer (score 3):

The YAML in the question is not idiomatic but it actually is very nearly legal. YAML requires a space after commas in lists which is missing on line 8.

Corrected YAML:

```
features: [
  {
    name: lorem ipsum,
    bullets: [
      "bullet 1",
      "bullet 2"
    ]
  }, {
    name: lorem ipsum 2,
    bullets: []
  }
]
```